# Trying to make an Array list of objects but app crashes with a null pointer exeption

Tags: java, android, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I have class Product:

```
public class Product {
     private String name;
     public Product(String name) {
         this.name = name;
     }
     public String getName() {
         return name;
     }
 }
```

Then in MainActivity:

```
ArrayList<Product> products;
....
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ..... 
    for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++){
        products.add(new Product(Integer.toString(i)));
    }
}
```

After compiling and building App crashes and give such error code:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{panchenko.ivan.canteen_application/panchenko.ivan.canteen_application.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object
>   reference

I don't have any ideas what goes wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `NullPointerException` means you are referencing a variable in your code that you haven't assigned - i.e. it is `null`. There is a great Stack Overflow answer on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/218510/4230345) that I would recommend you read through if you are new to this.

In your case, you are getting the `NullPointerException` because your `ArrayList<Product> products` is `null`:

You need to assign it before you can use it, so do this:

```
ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
```

instead of:

```
ArrayList<Product> products;
```

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList products = new ArrayList();

please see this its useful for starting https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/arraylist/arraylist-in-java-example-how-to-use-arraylist/